# Comparing Arrays - accumulator in method will not increment

Tags: java, arrays, accumulator

In the methods totalCorrect() and totalIncorrect() , I set up an var accumulator to count how many questions are right or wrong. For some reason, it will not increment properly. The program says that the user got 24, or 40 correct and incorrect... why won't it increment properly?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class driverExam {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Driver's Test. Input your answers for the following 
10 Q's. ");
    System.out.println();

    String[] testAnswers = {"B","D","A","A","C","A","B","A","C","D"};
    int uT = testAnswers.length; 
    String[] userAnswers = new String[uT];

    int i =0;
    while(i<uT) {
        System.out.print("Question #"+(i+1)+": ");
        String userInput = in.nextLine();
        userInput = userInput.toUpperCase();
        if (userInput.equals("A")|| userInput.equals("B")|| 
    userInput.equals("C")
                || userInput.equals("D")) {
            userAnswers[i] = userInput;
            i++;
        }else {
            System.out.println("Enter again: ");
        }
    }           

    System.out.println("Here are the results.");
    int qRight = totalCorrect(userAnswers,testAnswers);
    System.out.println("Total Correct: "+qRight);
    int qWrong = totalIncorrect(userAnswers, testAnswers);
    System.out.println("Total Incorrect: "+qWrong);
    System.out.println(passed(qRight));

    }
```

I am trying to increment the var "same" only when the array finds that the String in userAnswers is the same in testAnswers, and same for var "wrong" in the latter method.

```
    /**
    * @param user
    * @param test
    * @return
    */
public static int totalCorrect(String[] user,String[] test) {
    int same=0;
    for (int r = 0;r<=user.length-1;r++) {
        for (int k =0;k<=test.length-1;k++) {
            if(user[r].equals(test[k])) {
                same++;
            }
        }
    }
    return same;    
}

/**
 * @param user
 * @param test
 * @return 
 */
public static int totalIncorrect(String[] user,String[] test) {
    int z=0;
    int wrong = 0;
    boolean isValid = true;
    while (isValid && z<user.length) {
        if (user[z]!=test[z]) {
            isValid = false;
            wrong ++;
            z++;
        }
        }
    return wrongQ;
    }

/**
 * @param numRight
 * @return //returns whether student has passed or failed
 */
public static String passed(int numRight) {
    int goldenNum = 8;
    if (numRight >=goldenNum) {
        return ("You passed.");
    }else
        return ("You have failed.");
}

/**
 * @param user
 * @param test
 * @return
 */
public static int[] questionMissed(String[] user, String[] test) {
    //return array which display which questions were missed
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for each user answer whether it matches any of the test answers. You should only compare it to a single answer:

```
public static int totalCorrect(String[] user,String[] test) {
    int same=0;
    for (int r = 0;r<=user.length-1;r++) {
        if(user[r].equals(test[r])) {
            same++;
        }
    }
    return same;    
}
```

The total wrong answers should simply be the difference between all the answers and the correct answers, so you don't need a separate method for that purpose.

```
int qWrong = userAnswers.length - qRight;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need only 1 loop for checking the 2 array(in case the size of them are the same):

```
public static int totalCorrect(String[] user,String[] test) {
    int qRight = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i<user.length;i++) {
        if(user[i].equals(test[i])) {
            qRight++;
        }
    }
    return qRight;    
}

public static int totalIncorrect(String[] user,String[] test) {
    int qWrong=0;
    for (int i = 0;i<user.length;i++) {
        if(!user[i].equals(test[i])) {
            qWrong++;
        }
    }
    return qWrong;    
}
```

or you can reuse the the `totalCorrect` method:

```
public static int totalIncorrect(String[] user,String[] test) {
    int qRight=totalCorrect(user,test);

    return test.length - qRight;    
}
```